# How to read data from ".data" section of a process?

Tags: python, winapi, memory, process, portable-executable

So, as far as I understand from looking online, the `.data` section of the PE file contains the static and global variables of the program.

All I am trying to do is create a variable in Python, or write something in `notepad.exe`, and look it up in its memory using the Win32 API.

What I have done:

1. I looked into the PE file structure of `notepad.exe` and found the virtual address of its `.data` section.
2. I attached to the running process and found its base address, and then added the virtual address of the `.data` section to that (is this the right calculation? If not, I would appreciate any learning resources, as I couldn't find much).
3. I tried to read about 1000 bytes, and I found some data. But when looking for `hello` (in hex, of course), it didn't find anything.

For the sake of POC and simplicity, I am using the `Pymem` module to make the Win32 API calls.

Here is my code:

```py
import pymem
import pefile
process = pymem.Pymem('Notepad.exe')
process_module = list(process.list_modules())[0]
pe = pefile.PE(process_module.filename)
data_section = [x for x in pe.sections if b'.data' in x.Name][0]
section_address = process_module.lpBaseOfDll + data_section.VirtualAddress
section_size_to_scan = data_section.section_max_addr - data_section.section_min_addr
mem_dump = process.read_bytes(section_address, section_size_to_scan)
hello_in_hex = b'\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'
print(mem_dump)
print(hello_in_hex in mem_dump)
```

Obviously, the output is False.

Does anyone knows where I am making a mistake?

Comment: What makes you think `notepad.exe` has a static `hello` string stored in its `.data` section? The contents of `.data` are defined when the EXE is compiled, not when the EXE is run. Unless Notepad's source code contains a global `char[]` array defined like `char hello[] = "Hello";` or `char hello[] = {'H','e','l','l','o','};` (which is very unlikely), you are not going to find it this way. If you are writing `hello` into Notepad's UI and then trying to find it, it is not going to be stored in `.data` at all. So, this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: The section names are mostly convention. It is better to use the data directories or a RVA to locate things.